# Javascript Не могу разобраться с областями видимости переменных

Tags: javascript, переменные, область-видимости

Читаю данные по акциям из файла MoexListJson.json , на их основе строю запрос для чтения данных из следующего файла с ценами. Не понимаю как передать данные из тела запроса второй функции чтения файла наружу, чтобы с ними можно было работать.

Подсказки по предыдущим вопросам "Области видимости переменных в JS" не помогли. Прошу помощи.

```
fs.readFile('\MoexListJson.json', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    stocks = JSON.parse(data);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) {
      var NAME = stocks[i].TICKER;
      console.log(NAME + '/' + i);
      path = 'HistPrices\\' + NAME + '.json';
      fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8', function(err, dt) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {}
      }) //last readFile
      console.log(data);
      console.log(dt);
    } //end of i cycle
  } //first else

}) //first readFile
```

Comment: Вопрос как минимум ужасен. Но сразу бросается в глаза: `console.log(dt)` -  в этом месте "dt" не существует.

Comment: @pomorets у тебя колбек заканчивается перед `console.log` `data` и `dt`, и ты читаешь из него пелеменные

Comment: Спасибо, за подсказку. Разобрался.